# Random CSS not working in Heroku deployment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app that I've deployed to Heroku, and a few recent changes I've made in CSS (one batch of which is some media queries) just aren't working. They are present in the CSS when I look at the page source, though.

I'm running `be rake assets:precompile` before I push to heroku, and my config/production file is:

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
 config.assets.compile = true
 config.assets.digest = true
 config.log_level = :debug

 config.i18n.fallbacks = true
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new 
 config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
 end
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to ensure that my CSS is all working correctly? Could this be some kind of cache issue?

I'm new to heroku, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

and push all compressed js, css and manifest file on heroku and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...........

By default Rails will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into config/application.rb and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same result by including the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

This gem will configure your application to serve static assets so that you do not need to do this manually in a config file.

Hope this will work for you.